# .map() method using prior state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

My app allows users to click on player cards in a Field section, and then for the selected player cards to appear in a Teams section. I have an array (called selectedPlayers) and initially, each element has a default player name and default player image. As the users select players, the elements in the array are replaced one-by-one by the name and image of the selected players.

The state of the array is set in a parent component and then the array is passed to a TeamsWrapper component as a prop. I then map through the array, returning a TeamsCard component for each element of the array. However, my TeamsCards are always one selection behind reality. In other words, after the first player is selected, the first card still shows the default info; after the second player is selected, the first card now reflects the first selection, but the second card still shows the default info. The code for the TeamsWrapper component is below:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import TeamsCard from "../TeamsCard";

function TeamsWrapper(props) {
  const { selectedPlayers } = props;
  console.log('first console.log',selectedPlayers)
  return (
    <div className="teamsWrapper">
      {selectedPlayers.map((el, i) => {
        console.log('second console.log',selectedPlayers)
        console.log('third console.log',el)
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <TeamsCard
              image={el.image}
              playerName={el.playerName}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TeamsWrapper;
```

I did have this working fine before when the parent was a class-based component. However, I changed it to a function component using hooks for other purposes. So, I thought the issue was related to setting state, but the console logs indicate something else (I think). After the first player is selected:

- the first console log shows a correctly updated array (i.e. the first element reflects the data for the selected player, not the placeholder data)
- the second console log reflects the same
- but the third print still shows the placeholder data for the first element

As mentioned above, as I continue to select players, this third print (and the TeamsCards) is always one selection behind.

EDIT:

Here is the code for the parent component (Picks), but I edited out the content that was not relevant to make it easier to follow.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useStateWithCallbackLazy } from "use-state-with-callback";
import TeamsWrapper from "../TeamsWrapper";
import FieldWrapper from "../FieldWrapper";

const Picks = () => {
  const initialSelectedPlayers = [
    { playerName: "default name", image: "https://defaultimage" },
    { playerName: "default name", image: "https://defaultimage" },
    { playerName: "default name", image: "https://defaultimage" },
    { playerName: "default name", image: "https://defaultimage" },
    { playerName: "default name", image: "https://defaultimage" },
    { playerName: "default name", image: "https://defaultimage" },
  ];

  const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallbackLazy(0);
  const [selectedPlayers, setSelectedPlayers] = useState(
    initialSelectedPlayers
  );

  const handleFieldClick = (props) => {
    // check to make sure player has not already been picked
    const match = selectedPlayers.some(
      (el) => el.playerName === props.playerName
    );
    if (match) {
      return;
    } else {
      setCount(count + 1, (count) => {
        updatePickPhase(props, count);
      });
    }
  };

  const updatePickPhase = (props, count) => {
    if (count <= 15) {
      updateTeams(props, count);
    }
    // elseif other stuff which doesn't apply to this issue
  };

  const updateTeams = (props, count) => {
    const location = [0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3];
    const position = location[count - 1];
    let item = { ...selectedPlayers[position] };
    item.playerName = props.playerName;
    item.image = props.image;
    selectedPlayers[position] = item;
    setSelectedPlayers(selectedPlayers);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TeamsWrapper selectedPlayers={selectedPlayers}></TeamsWrapper>
      <FieldWrapper
        handleFieldClick={handleFieldClick}
        count={count}
      ></FieldWrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default Picks;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This component should work like you expect. We need to see the parent where the state is stored. Something that may be catching you out is that if you modify the array, the console will reflect that, even if you logged it before modifying it. In general when updating state you should create new objects instead of modifying previous ones.

Comment: Ben, thank you for the thoughts and the tip about console logging. Parent component has been added although I had to simplify it a bit to focus on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the array you are mutating state (updating existing variable instead of creating a new one), so React doesn't pick up the change and only re-render when `count` changes, try

```
const updateTeams = (props, count) => {
  const position = count - 1;
  const newPlayers = [...selectedPlayers];
  newPlayers[position] = {playerName:props.playerName, image:props.image} 
  setSelectedPlayers(newPlayers);
};
```

This way React will see it is a new array and re-render.